# User Not Deleted In Firebase

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-authentication

I have an app that allows a user to sign in and sign out. As per App Store rules, I have to allow a user to be able to delete their account. I am using the default function from Firebase to delete account:

```
func deleteUser() {
        let user = Auth.auth().currentUser
        
        user?.delete { error in
            if let error = error {
                print("Error with deleting user")
            } else {
                print("User Deleted")
                try? Auth.auth().signOut()
                self.userisLoggedIn = false
            }
        }
    }
```

But when I check my firebase auth, the user is still there. I still get the `User Deleted` print dialouge.

Comment: Retagging as `swift`, as this doesn't have anything to do with `SwiftUI`

Comment: If you wrap it to `Try Catch` block, you will know that user has to be fresh logged in to be able to delete account. So first log in user with email and password, then after that delete account.

Comment: yeah, wrapping it inside of a `Try Catch Block` worked.

Answer (score 0):

Button to fix the view:

```
Button {
    do {
        try deleteUser()
    } catch {
        print("error with deleting user")
    }
} label: {
    Text("Delete My Account")
}.buttonStyle(.bordered)
```